# Apache Virtual Host Not Working

Tags: apache-httpd, raspbian, apache-virtualhost

I'm trying to set up Apache virtual hosts on my Raspberry Pi so I can host 2 different websites with 2 different domains. I've done it before with no problems, but now I'm having no luck.

Since setting up the virtual hosts, all SSL connections are now refused (`ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`) and any HTTP connections go straight to the server root (`var/www`).

My virtual host files look like this:

```
    <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName roboguy99.co.uk
        </VirtualHost>
        <VirtualHost *:443>
            ServerAdmin roboguy99@gmail.com
            ServerAlias www.roboguy99.co.uk
            ServerName roboguy99.co.uk
            DocumentRoot /var/www/roboguy99.co.uk/public_html
            ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
            CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
            SSLEngine on
            SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt
            SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key
            <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
            </FilesMatch>
            <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
            </Directory>
            BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
                            nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
                            downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
            BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown
        </VirtualHost> 
    </IfModule>
```

and

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName choughsttc.co.uk
    </VirtualHost>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin roboguy99@gmail.com
    ServerAlias www.choughsttc.co.uk
        ServerName choughsttc.co.uk
        DocumentRoot /var/www/choughsttc.co.uk/public_html
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key
        <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </FilesMatch>
        <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </Directory>
        BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
                        nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
                        downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
        BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown
    </VirtualHost> 
</IfModule>
```

And my `ports.conf` like this:

```
# If you just change the port or add more ports here, you will likely also
# have to change the VirtualHost statement in
# /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default
# This is also true if you have upgraded from before 2.2.9-3 (i.e. from
# Debian etch). See /usr/share/doc/apache2.2-common/NEWS.Debian.gz and
# README.Debian.gz

NameVirtualHost *:80
Listen 80

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    # If you add NameVirtualHost *:443 here, you will also have to change
    # the VirtualHost statement in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl
    # to <VirtualHost *:443>
    # Server Name Indication for SSL named virtual hosts is currently not
    # supported by MSIE on Windows XP.
    NameVirtualHost *:443
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    NameVirtualHost *:443
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

It's probably worth noting that my server was previously set up to work with 1 domain which automatically redirected all HTTP traffic to SSL (and was working fine).

I did have many a Google in search for a solution, however found nothing. If the soultion is stupidly easy, I'm sorry. If you need to see more files, I'll upload them. All help is appriciated.

Comment: Are you getting anything in the log files? I'm not sure if you're aware but having multiple vhosts with SSL can be a real pain to setup. Have you tried things like https://www.digicert.com/ssl-certificate-installation-apache.htm and https://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/apache-multiple-ssl-certificates-using-sni.htm

Comment: @pcnate nothing in the log files. I'll have a look at those guides, thanks.

Comment: When having virtual host setup problems, the first port of call should always be the output of "apachectl -S" (or possibly "httpd -S"). Please add this to your post